# add multi rows to coupons sql with csv(one field only)

Tags: sql, csv, opencart

I have a a table with the structure:

[image]

I also have a csv containing all the coupon codes only.

I want to use the same values for the other fields (except id of course).

What would be the be the sql required to insert these rows?

Answer (score 0):

Using `phpMyAdmin` You can insert data from CSV only if it contains all of the required (`NOT NULL` column) values - the other (when missing) will be filled with defaults, NULL or auto_incremeneted. But Using this tool it is not possible to insert only codes from CSV and use some *same values for the other fields*. So here You have two options: either set the default values of that columns not being updated from CSV to the desired ones or create a PHP import script, that will do that for You (if You do not want to change the DB table schema).